# C program to convert string to floating point

Tags: c, parsing, floating-point

From K&R:

> Extend `atof` to handle scientific notation of the form
>   123.45e-6
>   where a floating-point number may be followed by `e` or `E` and an optionally
>   signed exponent.

I only added the part that handles the scientific notation. It compiles and works fine. I think it's way too long and could be shortened. I also don't like the names.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 20


double atof(const char *s){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; isspace(s[i]); ++i);
        /*skip white space*/

    int sign;
    sign = (s[i] == '-')? -1 : 1; /*The sign of the number*/

    if(s[i] == '-' || s[i] == '+'){
        ++i;
    }

    double value;
    for(value = 0.0; isdigit(s[i]); ++i){
        value = value * 10.0 + (s[i] - '0');
    }

    if(s[i] == '.'){
        ++i;
    }

    double power;
    for(power = 1.0; isdigit(s[i]); ++i){
        value = value * 10.0 + (s[i] - '0');
        power *= 10.0;
    }

    if(s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'E'){
        ++i;
    }
    else{
        return sign * value/power;
    }

    int powersign; /*The sign following the E*/
    powersign = (s[i] == '-')? -1 : 1;

    if(s[i] == '-' || s[i] == '+'){
        ++i;
    }

    int power2; /*The number following the E*/
    for(power2 = 0; isdigit(s[i]); ++i){
        power2 = power2 * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
    }

    if(powersign == -1){
        while(power2 != 0){
            power *= 10;
            --power2;
        }
    }
    else{
        while(power2 != 0){
            power /= 10;
            --power2;
        }
    }

    return sign * value/power;
}


int main(void){
    char string[MAX_SIZE];

    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);

    printf("%.9f", atof(string));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Won't your implementation conflict with the standard implementation from [`stdlib.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof)? So do you need to implement that yourself at all?

Comment: It may be instructive to see how your platform's `strtod` is implemented.  (or perhaps not, if it is full of platform-dependent trickery!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for including a test program - that's always valuable!

However, I'm going to change it, to parse a battery of test cases instead of reading from stdin:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    static const char *const strings[] = {
        /* these should parse fully */
        "12",
        "12.0",
        "08",                   /* not octal! */
        "+12.34",
        ".34",
        "\t \n2.",
        "1e0",
        "1e+0",
        "1e-0",
        "1.e4",
        ".1e-4",
        "-5e006",
        "-5e+16",
        "-.05",
        "-.0",
        "-1e6",
        /* these should parse only the initial part */
        "5c5",
        "10ee5",
        "0x06",                 /* not hex! */
        "--1" ,
        "-+1" ,
        "1e--4" ,
        "-1e.4",
        "1e 4",
        "1e-g",
        "", "foobar",           /* both 0 */
        " e5",                  /* also 0 */
        "-1e6",
        /* overflow/underflow */
        "1e500000",
        "1e-500000",
        "-1e500000",
        "-1e-500000",
    };

    static const int max = sizeof strings / sizeof strings[0];
    for (int i = 0;  i < max;  ++i)
        printf("%20s = > %.9g\n", strings[i], extended_atof(strings[i]));
}
```

(I changed the function name to `extended_atof()` so as to be safely distinct from the standard library `atof()`.)

Your implementation passes all these tests.  Now we can look at refactoring.

### Remove duplication

The things that we parse in multiple places are:

- optional sign `+` or `-`
- digit sequences

So perhaps we can refactor each of those into a function?  Instead of using an integer index into the supplied string, I prefer to just move the string pointer, and eliminate the need for `i`:

```
/* return true for positive, false for negative,
   and advance `*s` to next position */
static bool parse_sign(const char **s)
{
    switch (**s) {
    case '-': ++*s; return false;
    case '+': ++*s; return true;
    default: return true;
    }
}
```

Let's make use of that in the function:

```
double extended_atof(const char *s)
{
    /*skip white space*/
    while (isspace(*s))
        ++s;

    int sign = parse_sign(&s) ? 1 : -1; /*The sign of the number*/

    double value = 0.0;
    while (isdigit(*s))
        value = value * 10.0 + (*s++ - '0');

    if (*s == '.') {
        ++s;
    }

    double power = 1.0;
    while (isdigit(*s)) {
        value = value * 10.0 + (*s++ - '0');
        power *= 10.0;
    }

    if (tolower(*s) == 'e') {
        ++s;
    } else {
        return sign * value/power;
    }

    bool powersign = parse_sign(&s); /*The sign following the E*/

    int power2 = 0.0; /*The number following the E*/
    while (isdigit(*s))
        power2 = power2 * 10.0 + (*s++ - '0');

    if (powersign) {
        while (power2 != 0) {
            power /= 10;
            --power2;
        }
    } else {
        while (power2 != 0) {
            power *= 10;
            --power2;
        }
    }

    return sign * value/power;
}
```

It's slightly shorter, and it still passes all the tests.

Let's see if we can read digit strings in a function, and replace the three places we do that.  We'll make it update a count of how many digits wore parsed, so we don't lose leading zeros in the fractional part:

```
double extended_atof(const char *s)
{
    /*skip white space*/
    while (isspace(*s))
        ++s;

    int sign = parse_sign(&s) ? 1 : -1; /*The sign of the number*/

    double value = parse_digits(&s, NULL);

    if (*s == '.') {
        ++s;
        int d;                  /* digits in fraction */
        double fraction = parse_digits(&s, &d);
        while (d--)
            fraction /= 10.0;
        value += fraction;
    }

    value *= sign;

    if (tolower(*s) == 'e') {
        ++s;
    } else {
        return value;
    }

    bool powersign = parse_sign(&s); /*The sign following the E*/

    int power2 = parse_digits(&s, NULL); /*The number following the E*/

    double power = 1.0;
    if (powersign) {
        while (power2 != 0) {
            power /= 10;
            --power2;
        }
    } else {
        while (power2 != 0) {
            power *= 10;
            --power2;
        }
    }

    return value/power;
}
```

Tests still pass; what's next?

```
if (tolower(*s) == 'e') {
    ++s;
} else {
    return value;
}
```

This can be reversed, and if we're returning, it doesn't matter what we do to `s`:

```
if (tolower(*s++) != 'e')
    return value;
```

Here's some near-duplicate blocks:

```
double power = 1.0;
if (powersign) {
    while (power2 != 0) {
        power /= 10;
        --power2;
    }
} else {
    while (power2 != 0) {
        power *= 10;
        --power2;
    }
}
```

Dividing by 10 is the same as multiplying by 0.1, so we can move the test into the loop:

```
double power = 1.0;
while (power2 != 0) {
    power *= powersign ? 0.1 : 10;
    --power2;
}
```

We could go further, and capture `powersign ? 0.1 : 10` into a variable.  We can also eliminate the `power` variable from here, and multiply `value` directly:

```
const double exponentsign = parse_sign(&s) ? 10. : .1;
int exponent = parse_digits(&s, NULL);

while (exponent--)
    value *= exponentsign;
```

## Final version

Here's what I finished up with:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* return true for positive, false for negative,
   and advance `*s` to next position */
static bool parse_sign(const char **const s)
{
    switch (**s) {
    case '-': ++*s; return false;
    case '+': ++*s; return true;
    default: return true;
    }
}

/* return decimal value of digits,
   advancing `*s` to the next character,
   and storing the number of digits read into *count */
static double parse_digits(const char **const s, int *const count)
{
    double value = 0.0;
    int c = 0;
    while (isdigit(**s)) {
        value = value * 10.0 + (*(*s)++ - '0');
        ++c;
    }
    if (count)
        *count = c;
    return value;
}

double extended_atof(const char *s)
{
    /*skip white space*/
    while (isspace(*s))
        ++s;

    const bool valuesign = parse_sign(&s); /* sign of the number */
    double value = parse_digits(&s, NULL);

    if (*s == '.') {
        int d;                  /* number of digits in fraction */
        ++s;
        double fraction = parse_digits(&s, &d);
        while (d--)
            fraction /= 10.0;
        value += fraction;
    }

    if (!valuesign)
        value = -value;

    if (tolower(*s++) != 'e')
        return value;

    /* else, we have an exponent; parse its sign and value */
    const double exponentsign = parse_sign(&s) ? 10. : .1;
    int exponent = parse_digits(&s, NULL);
    while (exponent--)
        value *= exponentsign;

    return value;
}


/* Test program */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    static const char *const strings[] = {
        /* these should parse fully */
        "12",
        "12.0",
        "08",                   /* not octal! */
        "+12.34",
        ".34",
        "\t \n2.",
        "1e0",
        "1e+0",
        "1e-0",
        "1.e4",
        ".1e-4",
        "-5e006",
        "-5e+16",
        "-.05",
        "-.0",
        "-1e6",
        /* these should parse only the initial part */
        "5c5",
        "10ee5",
        "0x06",                 /* not hex! */
        "--1" ,
        "-+1" ,
        "1e--4" ,
        "-1e.4",
        "1e 4",
        "1e-g",
        "", "foobar",           /* both 0 */
        " e5",                  /* also 0 */
        "-1e6",
        /* overflow/underflow */
        "1e500000",
        "1e-500000",
        "-1e500000",
        "-1e-500000",
    };

    static const int max = sizeof strings / sizeof strings[0];
    for (int i = 0;  i < max;  ++i)
        printf("%20s = > %.9g\n", strings[i], extended_atof(strings[i]));
}
```

---

There's still an opportunity for a small improvement: an extremely long fractional part could overflow `double` (this problem existed in your original).  Instead of returning a large value from `parse_int()`, you could consider always returning a fractional value in the range [0...1), and use the number of digits to scale up the integer parts.  Then we'd just end up with lost precision at the lower end.  That would look like:

```
static double parse_digits(const char **const s, int *const count)
{
    double value = 0.0;
    double increment = 0.1;
    int c = 0;
    while (isdigit(**s)) {
        value += increment * (*(*s)++ - '0');
        increment /= 10;
        ++c;
    }
    if (count)
        *count = c;
    return value;
}
```

The corresponding uses would be:

```
double extended_atof(const char *s)
{
    /*skip white space*/
    while (isspace(*s))
        ++s;

    int d;                  /* number of digits */
    const bool valuesign = parse_sign(&s); /* sign of the number */
    double value = parse_digits(&s, &d);
    while (d--)
        value *= 10;

    if (*s == '.') {
        ++s;
        double fraction = parse_digits(&s, NULL);
        value += fraction;
    }

    if (!valuesign)
        value = -value;

    if (tolower(*s++) != 'e')
        return value;

    /* else, we have an exponent; parse its sign and value */
    const double exponentsign = parse_sign(&s) ? 10. : .1;
    double exponent_f = parse_digits(&s, &d);
    while (d--)
        exponent_f *= 10;

    unsigned long exponent = exponent_f;
    while (exponent-->0)
        value *= exponentsign;

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Some corer cases: 1) `isspace(*s)` is UB if `*s < 0` (and not `EOF`).  Same for `tolower()`.  Could use `isspace((unsigned char) *s)` 2) `value` computation and `exponent_f *= 10;` can overflow (or UF to 0) before `value *= exponentsign;` even thought the result would otherwise be in range.  `"0.17e309"`, `"2.22e-308"`.  3) `parse_digits()` introduces  lots of rounding errors (weakness), builds up `value` from MSdigits to LSD - which is numerically less accurate than the reverse.   Yet does handle not OF readily (strength).  Still overall a good `atof()`

Comment: Dividing by 10.0 is _not_ the same as multiplying with 0.1.

Comment: @Roland, in general I agree, `*.1`  and `/10.` aren't necessarily identical, but *in this specific case* (decimal->float conversion), the difference is significant.

Comment: @chux: several good points - thank you!  I'll see if I can find time to re-work a solution with those facts taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the **worst case of duplication** that you need to remove from your code is writing another set of lines for reading the floating number after e (/E).

Even I am just a beginner and doing K&R right now. Here's what I thought when doing the exercise:

For extending the program to handle scientific notations the first thing that I require is to read another floating point number after the character e/E. The code for doing this is already present in the function. Which makes it obvious that we are to reuse that code somehow. I thought that no extra lines of code should should be written for implementing this functionality.

I found that using recursion along with math.h library shortened and simplified the code (particularly the part used for reading the number following e/E) quite considerably.

Here's the code that I wrote:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

double atof(char *);

int main(void)
{
    char num[20];
    scanf("%19s", num);
    double number=atof(num);
    printf("\n%lf", number);
    return 0;
}

double atof(char *num)
{
    double val=0.0;
    int place=1;
    double expo=1.0;
    int i=0;
    int sign=1;
    for(; isspace(num[i]); i++);    //skip spaces
    sign=(num[i]=='-')?-1:1;    //determine sign
    if(num[i]=='-'||num[i]=='+')
        ++i;

    while(isdigit(num[i])){ //digits before decimal
        val=(val*10)+(num[i]-'0');
        ++i;
    }

    if(num[i]=='.')  //skip decimal point if present
        ++i;

    while(isdigit(num[i])){ //digits after decimal
        val=val*10+(num[i]-'0');
        place*=10;
        i++;
    }

    if(num[i]=='e' || num[i]=='E'){  //the extended part for scientific notations
        ++i;
        expo=pow(10,atof(num+i));
    }
    return (sign*val*expo)/(place);
}
```

Comment: Same issues as with [this comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158519/c-program-to-convert-string-to-floating-point#comment300643_158600).  `atof(&num[i])` is curious.  I'd expect `expo=pow(10,atoi(&num[i]));`  This does not pass `"1E10"` (only `e` passes)

Comment: @chux didn't get what you mean by `atoi(&num[i]))`

Comment: This answer's `expo=pow(10,atof(num+i));` calls `atof()`, which returns `double`,  to parse a string encoding an  integer.  As the exponent is an integer I'd expect code to use `atoi()` rather than `atof()`.

Comment: @chux Isn't it better if the program handles floating point exponents as well?

Comment: Better - perhaps, yet certainly unexpected.   So this code would handle `"0.5e0.4e0.3e0.2e0.1"` as 11.8...  I'd expect 0.5 or error return of 0.0.    IAC, `atof()` error behavior is undefined, so this answer's handling of unusual strings is not wrong.